# Enumerating translated .resx resources at runtime in WPF application

Tags: wpf, localization, resources, internationalization, resx

I've been doing localization for my WPF application by storing strings in .resx files. My default (english) string resource is strings.resx. For other languages are called strings.fr-FR.resx for French, strings.es-ES.resx for Spanish and so on.

This method of localization has been great as my app will automatically load up the right string when I set the Globalization region to a matching locale, and defaults to English when there isn't.

Is it possible at runtime to enumerate which languages are in my Assembly?

I could get around this and hard code in which languages are included, but this can change from build to build as a build server is putting together the language resx's and building dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options, none of which is ideal...

- Enumerate all known cultures (CultureInfo.GetCultures), and try to get a given ressource for this culture => simple but slow
- Look for satellite assemblies in your application's directory : for each subdirectory, check if it's name corresponds to a culture name (CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo), and if it contains a .resources.dll file

Comment: Regarding option (2) and the way the question was asked, wouldn't the default resx just be part of the main assembly and not have an "en_US" directory to look for? I know this is an olie, but I have an open question that related to this. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl, yes, the resources for the default culture are always in the main assembly (but it's not necessarily en-US...)

Comment: So if you elected to just have the main.resx and no en-US, and wanted to enumerate available resource cultures - you would find all subdirectories and then what? Is there anything about the main assembly resx that definitively says the strings were "en-US"? Cheers

Comment: @Berryl, the culture of the main assembly's resources can be indicated with the [NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I'll give you the answer in the other question also.